# Maven How to execute another command incase of some other commands failure

Tags: windows, ant, exec-maven-plugin

Here I have problem in maven something like that

```
.....
<tasks>
    <exec executable="subst" failonerror="false">
        <arg line="f: c:\blabla"/>
    </exec>
////// here the execution I try to make!
    <exec executable="subst" failonerror="false" if=//before execution fails!>
        <arg line="g: c:\blabla"/>
    </exec>
<tasks>
```

I couldnt imagine how to run a command in case of another commands fail.

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

Those are Ant tasks. It only has anything to do with Maven because you're using the Antrun plugin. You should take a look [the manual page for the Ant exec task](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/exec.html). In particular, you'll probably be interested in the "resultproperty" attribute. That will let you capture the exit code of the process and then you can make decisions based on it.